# How to implement partial specialized template on void separate from definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

I have a problem in separating the implementations of an inner class while having partial specializations. Here is a sample code that illustrate my problem:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using enable_if_copyable = std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value>;

template <typename T>
using enable_if_not_copyable = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value>;

template <typename T, typename Enabled=void> 
struct Foo;

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, enable_if_copyable<T>>
{
    struct Bar
    {
        Bar();
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo<T, enable_if_not_copyable<T>> {
    struct Bar
    {
        Bar();
    };
};

template <>
struct Foo<void,void>
{
    struct Bar
    {
        Bar();
      //Bar() {} This compiles, but it is not what I want.
    };
};

template <typename T>
Foo<T, enable_if_copyable<T>>::Bar::Bar()
{}    

template <typename T>
Foo<T, enable_if_not_copyable<T>>::Bar::Bar()
{}

template <>
Foo<void, void>::Bar::Bar() // this does not compile
{}


int main() {
    Foo<int>::Bar b;
    Foo<void>::Bar v;
}
```

Because of dependencies I have to implement the c'tors of `Bar` outside their declaration.
My problem is that all compiler (Clang, gcc, Visual Studio 2015) complain about the implementation of `Foo<void, void>::Bar::Bar() {}` outside of the declaration of `class Foo<void, void>`. If I implement the c'tor of `Bar` inside the specialization on `void`, I don't have any problem.
Is this is not doable or is there one who could help me to spot my problem?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting the `template<>`; i mean:

```
// template <>
Foo<void, void>::Bar::Bar() // now compile
{}
```

See [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) for further details.

Comment: Yes - the key here is that `Foo<void, void>::Bar::Bar()` is not itself an explicit specialization. It's a member of an explicit specialization.